# Implement inner non-static interface

Tags: interface, ceylon

I would like to instantiate an an inner non-static interface from outside the wrapping class.

Is this possible?

Consider the following code:

```java
shared class AOuterClass() {
Integer val = 3;
shared interface AInterface {
        shared Integer val => outer.val;
    }
}

void test() {
    AOuterClass o = AOuterClass();
    object impl satisfies ???.AInterface{}
}
```

I think `object impl satisfies o.AInterface{}` would be my reasonable intuition, but the compiler does not allow it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**It is not possible in a case like your one.**

The Ceylon specification says ([section 4.5.4 Class Inheritance](https://www.ceylon-lang.org/documentation/1.3/spec/html/declarations.html#classinheritance)):

> A subclass of a nested class must be a member of the type that declares the nested class or of a subtype of the type that declares the nested class. A class that satisfies a nested interface must be a member of the type that declares the nested interface or of a subtype of the type that declares the nested interface.

So you can only satisfy a nested interface inside the declaring class, or in a subclass thereof. Similar language is there for extending a nested interface by a new interface.

This does not directly mention `object` declarations, but those are merely a shortcut for class definitions, as elaborated a bit later, in [Anonymous classes](https://www.ceylon-lang.org/documentation/1.3/spec/html/declarations.html#anonymousclasses):

> The following declaration:
>
> ```ceylon
> shared my object red extends Color('FF0000') {
>      string => "Red";
> }
> ```
>
> Is exactly equivalent to:
>
> ```ceylon
> shared final class \Ired of red extends Color {
>      shared new red extends Color('FF0000') {}
>      string => "Red";
> }
>
> shared my \Ired red => \Ired.red;
> ```
>
> Where `\Ired` is the type name assigned by the compiler.

So this also covers `object` declarations as your one.

What you might be able to do (I didn't test this):

```ceylon
AOuterClass.AInterface test(){
    object o extends AOuterClass() {
       shared object impl satisfies AInterface{}
    }
    return o.impl;
}
```

Of course, this doesn't work for an existing `AOuterClass` object, just for a newly created one. Seeing that this allows accessing a private value of an object, this seems to be a good thing.

Comment: I agree, that's the simplest solution. (And yes, it does work.)

Comment: The idea was to create and implement the interface from outside for a given`o`. (But it was also just an idea and it is not important, I just wondered if I there is some syntax trick)